# Ubuntu Touch - Installing from the Store with Ubuntu-One-Account

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, nexus-4

Just installed **Ubuntu Touch** aka Ubuntu Phone on my old Nexus and I really like the design! Now, I wanted to test installing apps from the Ubuntu Store et voila, it asks me for an Ubuntu-One-Account (which doesn't exist anymore).

How can I install this App with Ubuntu-One being out of service?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu One **file service** is gone, but you can still create an account [here](https://login.ubuntu.com).

Comment: Thank you, now I got it. An account is enough to use it on the phone.